# Como a melhor forma de fazer WHERE's condicionais com o ActiveRecord no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Estou trabalhando com JSON no Rails. Imagine a rota:

```
# rota: pessoas.json
def index
  @pessoas = Pessoa.all
end
```

Isso é fácil! Mas se eu quiser adicionar uma busca opcional por idade teria que ter uma condição:

```
# rota: pessoas.json?idade=30
def index
  if params[:idade]
    @pessoas = Pessoa.where("idade = ?", params[:idade])
  else
    @pessoas = Pessoa.all
  end
end
```

Isso não é o fim do mundo, mas fica mais difícil com mais parâmetros opcionais:

```
pessoas.json
pessoas.json?idade=30
pessoas.json?sexo=m
pessoas.json?idade=30&sexo=m
```

Qual a melhor forma (mais DRY) de fazer essa busca em que os parâmetros são opcionais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `where` aceita [um hash de condições como parâmetro](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where-label-hash). Então, nesse caso você poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
@pessoas = Pessoa.where(params)
```

Caso você queira restringir os filtros permitidos você poderia usar o strong_parameters, como por exemplo:

```
@pessoas = Pessoa.where(params.permit(:idade, :sexo))
```

Caso você precise usar condições mais complexas, por exemplo, com uso de comparativos, então você poderia usar encadeamento:

```
@pessoas = Pessoa.all
@pessoas = @pessoas.where('idade >= ?', params[:idade_minima]) if params[:idade_minima]
@pessoas = @pessoas.where('sexo = ?', params[:sexo]) if params[:sexo]
```

Se forem muitas e você quiser deixar esse código DRY você poderia fazer:

```
@pessoas = Pessoa.all
condicoes = {
   idade_minima: 'idade >= ?',
   sexo: 'sexo = ?',
}
condicoes.each do |atributo, condicao|
   @pessoas = @pessoas.where(condicao, params[atributo]) if params[atributo]
end
```

Comment: Ótima resposta. A solução `Modelo.where( params.permit(...) )` é realmente a melhor no caso da busca por igualdade =)

Answer (score 1):

Use a gem [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

A forma mais "idiomática" de fazer, sem usar gems seria:

```
@pessoas = Pessoa.all
@pessoas = @pessoas.where("idade = ?", params[:idade]) if params[:idade]
```